# Issues with Geckoview (Firefox webview) Graddle conflict (lollipop version)

Tags: android, firefox, webview, geckoview

I am referring https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView 
and also using Exo Player.
which is creating a Gradle conflict.

```
[Error image][1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Axo.png
```

i have to try to exclude the exoplayer from Mozilla Gradle but still not working.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.5'
[![enter image description here][1]][1]implementation ('org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-nightly:70.0.20190712095934'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.exoplayer', module:'exoplayer-core'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.exoplayer', module:'exoplayer-dash'
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely caused by GeckoView using a copy of ExoPlayer internally for HLS support. It doesn't consume it via gradle, so you won't be able to exclude it that way. I think the only solution will be for GeckoView to use Proguard/R8 to obfuscate/rename the internal ExoPlayer classes or to drop the ExoPlayer usage entirely. I filed a bug to track this here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1585323

Answer (score 1):

They have renamed the `exoplayer` package in the latest version 84.0.20201028092421.
use below version in gradle:

```
 geckoviewChannel = "nightly"
 geckoviewVersion = "84.0.20201028092421"
```